# Condition based on previous step on GITLABCI

Tags: gitlab, conditional-statements, gitlab-ci

The build step is triggered only if there is change on Dockerfile-pentaho.

The run step needs to run everytime, if the build step was triggered I want to get the image with CI_PIPELINE_ID tag, if not I want to run it with the latest tag.

I need to run the step "run" with the script below if the build step is triggered:

- docker run --rm $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID --v files/pentaho/reps/:/pentaho-di/repo/

And if not I Need to run the script below:

- docker run --rm $PENTAHO_IMAGE:latest --v files/pentaho/reps/:/pentaho-di/repo/

I've tried to create a file with `touch $CI_PROJECT_DIR/success` on build step and check if it exists on run step, but I can't get it to work.

here's my gitlab-ci.yml.

```
services:
  - docker:19.03.1-dind

variables:
  PENTAHO_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY/xxxx/xxxxx/pentaho
  

stages:
  - build
  - run

.docker-configs: &docker-configs
  tags: 
    - interno
  image:
    name: docker/compose:1.24.1
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    BUILD_PENTAHO: latest
  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin "$CI_REGISTRY"
 
build-pentaho:
  <<: *docker-configs 
  stage: build   
  rules:
    - changes: 
        - Dockerfile-pentaho 
  script:
    - echo "Building pentaho docker image"
    - docker build -t $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID -f Dockerfile-pentaho .
    - docker push $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - touch $CI_PROJECT_DIR/success # creating file to check on running step

run-pentaho:
  <<: *docker-configs
  stage: run 
  script:
    - echo "Executando pentaho image"
    - | 
      if [[ -f success ]] ; then
        echo "condição true"
        docker run --rm $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID --v files/pentaho/reps/:/pentaho-di/repo/ 
      else
        echo "condição false"
        docker run --rm $PENTAHO_IMAGE:latest --v files/pentaho/reps/:/pentaho-di/repo/ 
      fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working with artifacts.

The final gitlab-ci:

```
services:
  - docker:19.03.1-dind

variables:
  PENTAHO_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY/xxxx/xxxxx/pentaho
  

stages:
  - build
  - run

.docker-configs: &docker-configs
  tags: 
    - interno
  image:
    name: docker/compose:1.24.1
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    BUILD_PENTAHO: latest
  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin "$CI_REGISTRY"
 
build-pentaho:
  <<: *docker-configs 
  stage: build   
  rules:
    - changes: 
        - Dockerfile-pentaho 
  script:
    - echo "Building pentaho docker image"
    - docker build -t $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID -f Dockerfile-pentaho .
    - docker push $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID  
    - echo "building ..." >> ./result.txt
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 3 minutes
    paths:
        - result.txt


run-pentaho:
  <<: *docker-configs
  stage: run 
  script:
    - echo "Executando pentaho image"
    - | 
      if [[ -f result.txt ]] ; then
        echo "condição true"
        docker run --rm $PENTAHO_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID --v files/pentaho/reps/:/pentaho-di/repo/ 
      else
        echo "condição false"
        docker run --rm $PENTAHO_IMAGE:latest --v files/pentaho/reps/:/pentaho-di/repo/ 
      fi
```